# Create a guest network with docker router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, home-networking, docker

I have a home ISP provided router and I would like the guest network to be isolated from my other things. On the my network I have a Linux machine running docker with a Wi-Fi not used possible to use as an AP. I would like the docker host machine to be in my personal network, but I would like it to run a docker container providing the router services to control and manage the guest network.

My home ISP router has no VLAN possibility but can bridge ports.

Is this possible? I know it is little information, but I am a pure newbie when it comes to networks. Please ask any questions to put me on the correct way forward

Here’s the idea:
Blue represents my private network. 
Red represents the Guest network.

[image]